# Treat NAs as zeros when adding vectors

Tags: r

Adding two vectors is easy:

```
> c(1:5) + c(6:10)
[1]  7  9 11 13 15
```

But since adding any number to NA gives NA, this happens:

```
> c(1,NA,3:5)+c(6:10)
[1]  7 NA 11 13 15
```

How can I add two vectors where there *may* be some NAs, treating them as zeros? I need to get this result:

```
> c(1,NA,3:5)+c(6:10)
[1]  7 7 11 13 15
```

Any ideas on how to do this using `{base}` and not changing the NAs to zeros on the original vectors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `colSums` or `rowSums`, e.g.:

```
rowSums(cbind(x, y), na.rm = T)
# [1]  7  7 11 13 15

colSums(rbind(x, y), na.rm = T)
# [1]  7  7 11 13 15
```

Benchmarks; surprisingly `colSums` works the fastest:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fn_replace(x, y),
                               fn_rowSums(x, y),
                               fn_colSums(x, y),
                               fn_coalesce(x, y))

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# fn_replace(x, y) 121.4322 130.99067 174.1531 162.2454 183.1781 385.7348   100
# fn_rowSums(x, y) 143.0654 146.20815 172.5396 149.3953 179.0337 370.1625   100
# fn_colSums(x, y)  96.8848  99.46521 121.5916 106.8800 140.9279 298.1607   100
# fn_coalesce(x, y) 259.2923 310.16915 357.0241 326.1245 360.9110 595.9711   100


## Code to generate x, y and functions for benchmark:
fn_replace <- function(x, y) {
    replace(x, is.na(x), 0) + replace(y, is.na(y), 0)
}

fn_rowSums <- function(x, y) {

    rowSums(cbind(x, y), na.rm = T)

}

fn_colSums <- function(x, y) {

    colSums(rbind(x, y), na.rm = T)

}

fn_coalesce <- function(x, y) {
    dplyr::coalesce(x, rep(0, length(x))) + 
    dplyr::coalesce(y, rep(0, length(y)))
}


n_rep <- 1e6
x <- as.numeric(rep(c(1, NA, 3:5, NA, NA, 5), n_rep))
y <- as.numeric(rep(c(NA, 6:9, NA, 3, 4), n_rep))
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `replace` `NA`'s with 0 and then add the vectors

```
x <- c(1,NA,3:5)
y <- c(6:10)

replace(x, is.na(x), 0) + replace(y, is.na(y), 0)
#[1]  7  7 11 13 15
```

Answer (score 2):

We could try using `coalesce()` from the `dplyr` package:

```
require(dplyr)

x <- c(1,NA,3:5)
y <- c(6:10)
coalesce(x, rep(0, 5)) + coalesce(y, rep(0, 5))
```

`coalesce(x, y)` works by taking the first non `NA` value from x, should that position have a non `NA` value, or from y, e.g.

```
x   rep(0, 5) => result
1   0            1
NA  0            0
3   0            3
4   0            4
5   0            5
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `base::replace()` and `dplyr::coalesce()` as above, we can also use `tidyr::replace_na()`:

```
library(tidyr)

replace_na(x, 0) + replace_na(y, 0)
#[1]  7  7 11 13 15
```